# How to allow the Drive File Picker access to the users Drive when running the app is executing as me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive File Picker in an application that is being executed as me. When a user clicks to select a file they are presented with the Drive Folder structure of me (the user the app is executing as).

In my code I'm referencing Session.getActiveUser so I know who the user is and can performs actions and present data appropriate for their account.

How can I have the Drive File Picker display the files from the active user and not my account? I'm thinking if this cannot be done in the application, how would I spawn a separate window that runs a different web app that executes as them and then capture the call back in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't (indeed) but what you can do is to let the app run as the user accessing the app and let this app call another app running as a service and that runs as you (and do what has to be done on your side).

You can use [urlFetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to call your app, adding necessary parameters to the url to identify the actual user (of the calling app) and other security/logging data (to prevent access from other source).

Depending on the complexity of your workflow , this can be simple or quite complex but feasible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the content of the current user's Google Drive you can do it by performing an Oauth and using Google Picker.

You can find more about Oauth here :

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()

Also note that user will have to enable the Drive Picker API for his account in order to perform an Oauth.

Then using the access token from the Oauth you can pass it to the Drive Picker to show the contents.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

When you deploy the app you have to select :

Execute the app as: User accessing the web app

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, but the application need to run as me. The app connects to a SQL database using JDBC and other services which need to run as me. How can I allow the users to select items from their Drive from the app?